# How to proof logic with axioms and modus ponens?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, proof-verification, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus

My last question was about how to derive Truth Tables from a given logic statement. Now that I think i can manage I have been bestowed with a new quest in my search of mathematical enlightenment. This quest comes from the awesome Logic in Action book/pdf that can be found [here](http://www.logicinaction.org/docs/lia.pdf) page 2-23, example 2.25:

[image: Logic in Action example 2.25]

So I need to invite people (I guess the most people).
So the most people are Mary and John, where Ann does not come.
so:

> Ann comes, John does not
>   $$ a \rightarrow \neg j $$
>   Ann comes if Mary does not come
>   $$ \neg m \rightarrow a $$
>   John comes if Mary or Ann comes
>   $$ a \rightarrow j $$
>   $$ m \rightarrow j $$

So to prove that when Ann does not come Mary and John do come I started with this:

Let's say that John does not come.
$$ a \rightarrow \neg j $$
$$ \neg m \rightarrow a $$
This conclusion tells me that Ann does not come, or she would be the only person invited. So Ann must be false
$$ \neg a $$
Next is to see if Mary or John comes.
$$ \neg a \rightarrow j $$ 
$$ m \rightarrow j $$
$$ \neg a \rightarrow m $$
Mary comes, because Ann does not, therefore John also comes

The question is... Am I doing the proof thing correct?
This is all very new to me, and the book does not explain very well.

ps. some reference to youtube videos that [ELI5](http://onlineslangdictionary.com/meaning-definition-of/eli5) would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given $a \to \neg j$ and the fact that John does not come, the following is incorrect:

> This conclusion tells me that Ann does not come, or she would be the
>   only person invited. So Ann must be false $\neg a$.

Modus ponens only works with a given antecedent as follows:

\begin{array}{l}
& a & \text{ Given }\\
& a \to \neg j & \text{ Given }\\
& \neg j & \text{ Modus ponens }\\
\end{array}

In other words, there's no variation to this, such as, for example that given the consequent, you can conclude the antecedent. It only works when the antecedent is known, either as a premise or as the consequent of some other argument. When that's the case, you can assert the consequent.

One of the axioms that the text gives is $((\neg \phi \to \neg \psi) \to (\psi \to \phi))$. Applying this, you can conclude $\neg a$ as follows:

\begin{array}{l}
& j & \text{ Premise }\\
& a \to \neg j & \text{ Premise }\\
& j \to \neg a & \text{ Axiom }\\
& \neg a & \text{ Modus ponens }\\
\end{array}

A similar method can be used to conclude $m$, and knowing $m$, it's easy to conclude $j$:

\begin{array}{l}
& \neg a & \text{ Premise }\\
& \neg m \to a & \text{ Premise }\\
& m \to j & \text{ Premise }\\
& \neg a \to m & \text{ Axiom (applied to 2nd premise) }\\
& m & \text{ Modus ponens}\\
& j & \text{ Modus ponens }\\
\end{array}

Comment: Thank you. In the example it says that the solution is $ \neg a, j, m $ so $ a $ must be $  \neg a $ i tried to proof this. How would you go about it?

Comment: @Igoranze. With just modus ponens and the information given, there's no way to conclude $\neg a$. That would require modus tollens or a different premise. I edited to show how a proof can be constructed to conclude $\neg j.$

Comment: I don't understand, why does the example 2.25 say that the solution is $ \neg a, j, m $ if that is not possible to proof?

Comment: @Igoranze. You have to use the axioms given in the book as well. I edited my answer to show how to apply one of the axioms.

Comment: Thanks, I will try to do some on my own. At Least you gave me a better understanding!